# Local image to text converter script

Tags: image, text, ascii, converters, ascii-art

I'm looking something that will convert an image to text art, similar to [this website](http://www.text-image.com/convert/ascii.html) but instead something I can install locally and use in scripts (or build into [a fun app](http://earthlingsoft.net/ASCII%20Projektor/)).

I've tried searching for one but all I get is a multitude of online versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [AALib](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aalib/)

Or, [Caca lib](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca)

Comment: Here's a few more from each submission in this contest page: http://www.jave.de/image2ascii/competition2001/contributions.html